# StreamBridge binding instead of EnableBinding and Output annotations which are deprecated since 3.1 version of Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: java, spring, avro, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have multiple APIs that talk with each other through kafka (produce and consume messages). In one of the APIs I produce messages based on an HTTP request trigger (when an endpoint is called, a meesage is produced and sent to kafka) with @Output and @EnableBinding annotations. These meesages are consumed by other APIs that subscribe to this topic.

Now, I try to migrate to the the new spring cloud stream functional programming model and from the documentation I concluded that StreamBridge with external source data is the approach needed for my case (https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.0/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_sending_arbitrary_data_to_an_output_e_g_foreign_event_driven_sources). However, I did not understand how the source, bindingName and destination topic should be configured properly in terms of naming convention when no source function is defined. I have the following configuration which successfully produces messages on "myFooTopic", but I noticed some strange logs when the application starts, as the binding seems to not be properly done:

application.properties:

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=listOfServers for kafka
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer= MyCustomKafkaPayloadAvroSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.properties.schema.registry.url=listOfServers for schema registry

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.user.destination=myUserTopic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.user.producer.useNativeEncoding=true
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.user.producer.partitionCount=1

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.user.producer.partitionKeyExpression=headers['partitionId']

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.autoCreateTopics=false
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.security.protocol=SSL
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.ssl.truststore.location=
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.ssl.truststore.type=
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.ssl.keystore.location=
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.ssl.keystore.type=
```

Furthermore, the code for StreamBridge is:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class EventPublisher {

    private final StreamBridge streamBridge;
    private static final String USER = "user";

    public void sendToChannel(String message) {
        log.info("sendToChannel - sending to channel hello event");

        try {
            if (streamBridge.send(USER, buildChannelMessage(message))) {
                log.info("sendToChannel - message was successfully sent ");
            } else {
                log.error("sendToChannel - failed to send message");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("sendToChannel - error while sending message on output binding {}", USER, e);
        }
    }

    private Message<HelloEventAvro> buildChannelMessage(String message) {
        HelloEventAvro helloEventAvro = HelloEventAvro.newBuilder()
                .setHelloMessage(message)
                .build();
        long timestamp = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();

        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(helloEventAvro)
                .setHeader("partitionId", 1)
                .setHeader("X-Timestamp", timestamp)
                .build();
    }
}
```

and among the dependencies used:

- spring-boot 2.6.2
- kafka-clients 2.8.1
- spring-cloud-stream 3.2.1
- spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka 3.2.1
- spring-integration-kafka 5.5.8

My questions are:

- is the binding of the producer to myUserTopic correct or do I need to add the property spring.cloud.stream.source=user?
- **"user"** bindingName is correct or it should respect the convention as "user-out-0" considering that I don't have a bean supplier configured?
- When the first message is produced after the application starts, I can see the following logs:

```
    Using kafka topic for outbound: myUserTopic (which is correct)
    Caching the binder: kafka
    Retrieving cached binder: kafka
    .....
    Channel 'unknown.channel.name' has 1 subscriber(s). (which is strange)
```

For the following messages produced, the log '**unknown.channel.name**' does not appear again.

I don't understand why the name of the channel is "**unknown**" instead of the output bindingName "**user**" provided in the application.properties configuration. Can you guide me to understand if there is any misconfiguration on my side? All the spring-cloud-stream examples from the documentation & github use StreamBridge with either dynamic destinations or SupplierConfiguration.

---

Edit:

I have a further question regarding testing of the above configuration. I tried to write a test for this particular use case of StreamBridge by following the examples from here ([https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/d8ed65a249ed4364b96d68f4f56b3d5b4de996a4/spring-cloud-stream/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/function/StreamBridgeTests.java#L716][1]) and adapt it for my above application.properties config and for some reason, the message received in the **outputDestination is null** for this test:

```
public class StreamBridgeTests {

    @Test
    public void testSendingMessageToDestination() {
        try (ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new SpringApplicationBuilder(TestChannelBinderConfiguration
                .getCompleteConfiguration(Application.class))
                .web(WebApplicationType.NONE).run()) {

            HelloEventAvro helloEventAvro = buildHelloEventAvro();

            Message<HelloEventAvro> helloEventAvroMessage = MessageBuilder
                    .withPayload(helloEventAvro)
                    .setHeader(CustomKafkaHeaders.PARTITION_ID.value(), helloEventAvro.getId())
                    .build();

            StreamBridge bridge = context.getBean(StreamBridge.class);
            bridge.send("user", helloEventAvroMessage);

            OutputDestination outputDestination = context.getBean(OutputDestination.class);
            Message<byte[]> message = outputDestination.receive(100, "user");
            assertThat(new String(message.getPayload())).contains("hello");
        }
    }
}
```

I dived deeper with debug and it seems that the outputDestination is created with one channel (myUserTopic.destination) and 2 messageQueues instead of 1, mentioned below:

- **user.destination** with size 0 (where "user" = my bindingName)
- **myUserTopic.destination** with size 1 and the helloEventAvroMessage produced

If I change the bindingName from "user" to the name of the kafka topic "myUserTopic" in the receive() method of OutputDestination, it works as expected: one channel is created (myUserTopic.destination) and 1 messageQueue (myUserTopic.destination):

```
public class StreamBridgeTests {

    @Test
    public void testSendingMessageToDestination() {
        try (ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new SpringApplicationBuilder(TestChannelBinderConfiguration
                .getCompleteConfiguration(Application.class))
                .web(WebApplicationType.NONE).run()) {

            HelloEventAvro helloEventAvro = buildHelloEventAvro();

            Message<HelloEventAvro> helloEventAvroMessage = MessageBuilder
                    .withPayload(helloEventAvro)
                    .setHeader(CustomKafkaHeaders.PARTITION_ID.value(), helloEventAvro.getId())
                    .build();

            StreamBridge bridge = context.getBean(StreamBridge.class);
            bridge.send("user", helloEventAvroMessage);

            OutputDestination outputDestination = context.getBean(OutputDestination.class);
            Message<byte[]> message = outputDestination.receive(100, "myUserTopic");
            assertThat(new String(message.getPayload())).contains("hello");
        }
    }
}
```

Considering the above, I still don't get how the bindingName from the send() method of StreamBridge works in correlation with the receive() method from OutputDestination (***shouldn't be the same name in both places if I have only one topic?*** ) and how it is resolved to the kafka topic destination name set.

[1]: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/d8ed65a249ed4364b96d68f4f56b3d5b4de996a4/spring-cloud-stream/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/function/StreamBridgeTests.java#L716)

Comment: I am not sure about the channel name, but the `...source` property just determines whether the binding is created during initialization, or on the first send (https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.2.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_sending_arbitrary_data_to_an_output_e_g_foreign_event_driven_sources - `However, if you want to pre-create an output binding at the initialization (startup) time...`; the binding name with StreamBridge is arbitrary, the `...in-n`, `...out-n` convention is for `Consumer<?>` and `Function<?, ?>` methods only.

Comment: Hello @GaryRussell and thank you for the quick answer. I edited the above question with a further one related to the testing of the StreamBridge binding configuration, if you can also have a look at that one.

Answer (score 0):

Binding convention is the same as before.
You use StreamBridge to send to a binding. If such binding does not exist it will be created and the actual destination name that corresponds to a binding is the same unless . . . (read on)

```
bridge.send("foo", message)
```

If you have an existing destination (e.g., `foo_destination`) on the broker you can do the destination mapping the same way as before

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.foo.destination=foo_destination
```

In other words all binding properties will be applied on the newly (just-in-time) created binding.

And as Gary stated in the comment if you use `spring.cloud.stream.source=foo`, the `foo` binding will be pre-created during the initialization however it will follow the same convention as if you had a function which means the actual binding name will be `foo-out-0`. This is intentional, but i'll skip explaining for ow to avoid loosing the main context of the question.